# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY after Guest User Security Update

Tags: visual-workflow, security, guest-user, access, userrecordaccess

This month salesforce is rolling out a new security updated that prevents public sharing of record data, except via Sharing Rules that only provide Read-Only access. In preparing for this shift, I have activated the security update in Sandbox and am creating Sharing Rules to ensure access via a public Site/Visualforce page with an embedded flow is not interupted. However, I'm experiencing weird behavior where the flow is unable to look-up record for one object (named Trainee) and another where it is unable to create a record in another object (Registration). What I find odd is that my sharing rules are letting it create new Trainee records, and it is able to lookup Trainee and Training records which are the two objects used to create a Registration record. Below is a snippet from the end of the unexepcted fault email I receive each time...

```
CREATE RECORDS: Create_Registration
Create one Registration__c record where:
Registration_Method__c = SEWI Website
Registration_Status__c = Registered
Registration_Type__c = In-Person
Trainee_EMail__c = {!E_Mail} (testing2@brandonholmes.net)
Trainees__c = {!TraineeID} (a0n0v000001l2q4AAA)
Training__c = {!TrainingSelected} (Test Training 1)
Result
Failed to create record.
Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id.
```

Can anyone provide insight into why there seems to be a fault occurring when it's clear the flow has access and is able to see all the necessary fields for record creation?

Comment: Is registration master detail to training?  If so look at the relationship field and you can see what level of access is required to create child records, and I'd bet it requires edit access.

Comment: @gorav Yes, registration is a Master detail relationship with both Training and Trainee to provide a bridge between the two. Are you referring to checking the field-level security of the Trainee and Training fields on the Registration record?

Comment: On each of the lookup fields, you can specify what level of access is required on the parent object, in order to create or edit records of the child object. Get to one of the lookup fields in setup and it should be right there. It's not field level security, it's a different beast.  It's just for master detail, as access to the detail side is controlled by the access to the parent